# Storing revision history in a dedicated API (Revision API / Changes API)

Tags: node.js, api, version, revision-history

Most of us are likely used to storing revision history in the same database where the final data is. This creates maintainability and possibly stability problems:

- Revision history is a fairly complicated system. If there are lots of APIs, it needs to be reimplemented in every API separately. If a bug is discovered, it needs to be fixed in every API separately.
- In most of the cases, revision history is not the primary use case, but it is the main contributor to database disk space and memory usage, so we are bulking our APIs database with lots of data of a relatively small value.

Let's say we would have a Revision API, that deals with revisions and other services only store the final state, possibly revision UUIDs too.

There are downsides to this solution too:

- Fetching revision history requires a round trip to another service.
- If that so called "Revision API" is experiencing technical difficulties, all services are unable to use their revision history.
- It is more difficult to keep revision history in synchronization with reality, since we likely do not want to deny CRUD requests simply because Revision API is down. For example, we might still want to let a user to save their changes. Otherwise we would spread the impact to a much wider range of functionality.

In our case, revision history is used by internal employees rather than final customers. Of course applications should work seamlessly for everybody, but we are still joining a less critical, but very resource hungry functionality with a critical functionality, that must be guaranteed a very high uptime.

What are your views on a centralized revision history? Is this something that should be avoided at all cost or is it already well-proven by real world use cases? I can see, that many major corporations have separate APIs for revision history, but I am not sure whether they actually store data in a separate database or simply use Revision API as a gateway service.